# Check if word exists in img alt tag

Tags: php, image, tags, match, alt

I have been looking around for a script like this, but haven't been able to find any matches yet.

I know you guys in here, think out of the box, therefore i ask you.

I want (with PHP) checking if my  **tags in a string is containing a specific word in their alt tag. For example if i am looking for the word gem** and my string is:

```
I have a gem <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="This is my gem"> ye well it is.
```

It should only tell me i have a true match, because gem is in my alt tag and therefore a match. A false match would be:

```
 I have a gem <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="This is my gems"> ye well it is.
```

Because i am looking for the word gem in the alt tag.
Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: use `DOMDocument`'s `->getAttribute` + `strpos`

Comment: @Ghost with `strpos`, both "gem" and "gems" would be matched. Better to use a regular expression with word boundaries.

Comment: @TomFenech yeah, probably use regex on the attribute value itself is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on [Ghost's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098372/check-if-word-exists-in-img-alt-tag#comment46427140_29098372) in the comments, here's a way you can solve your problem using the `DOMDocument` class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('I have a gem <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="This is my gem"> ye well it is.');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');
    if (preg_match('/\bgem\b/', $alt)) {
        echo "matched: $alt";
    }
}
```

This parses the string as HTML and loops through each of the `<img>` elements. It uses a regular expression with word boundaries `\b` to match occurrences of the word "gem".

Output:

```
This is my gem
```

Comment: This works great! But having kind of trouble puttning my string as the matching word, can you help me out?

`$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($row['content']);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    if (preg_match('\\b' + $row_meta['keyword'] + '\\b', $img->getAttribute('alt'))) {
        $counter++;
    }
}`

Comment: @Jonas I've edited my answer, hopefully it does what you want now.

Comment: I cant exactly get it working with this:  `if (preg_match('/\b".$row_meta[keyword]."\b/', $alt)) {`

Comment: @Jonas without knowing what `$row_meta['keyword']` is, it's difficult to say why. By the way you should always quote your array keys.

Comment: $row_meta['keyword'] is a word from my database output. Right now it contains **test** and i have 3 pictures with the alt test. `With if (preg_match('/\b$key\b/', $alt)) {` it doesnt work, but if i replace $key with just test it works great. The thing is $key can be changed in the database and therefor i can not just type a specific word, but need it to be my string

Comment: I got it working with `if (preg_match("/\b".$key."\b/", $alt)) { ` thx alot! ill mark your answer as accepted. Have a good day!

Comment: @Jonas no problem. Remember that you need to use double quotes in order to interpolate a variable: `"/\b$key\b/"` - however, it is good practice to use `preg_quote` to catch characters that may otherwise be interpreted by the regular expression engine: `'/\b' . preg_quote($key, '/') . '\b/'`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out something like

```
preg_match_all('/<img.*?alt="(.*?)".*>/',$row[content], $match);
```

Probably would work, but when i try to print out $match[1] i only get the text "array"

Comment: you should have edited your question instead of posting this as an answer, or completely solve it and edit this post

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$var_string = your html img code;

if (strpos($var_string,'gem') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question - he only wants to search inside the alt tag, not the entire string.

Comment: As bulk answered, he is right. Thats kind of the tricky part.